# Connecting 2 PCs

Tags: networking

I have a very old windows 98 pc that has a network card on PCI that has 2 entrances on it (both RJ-11 one has "in" next to it and the secon 
"out").

I'd like to connect this pc to my new laptop which has a normal RJ-45 Ethernet entrance, because I have some files I wanted to transfer out of that old pc. Is there any way to do this?

If cables would be needed to be maked, that's no problem. Of course setting the IPs and all is clear to me, W just want to know if W can connect these computers using an RJ-11 to RJ-45 connection. If that wouldn't be possible, what could work in this situation? (There are no USB ports on this pc and no CD burner)

Also, I wanted to ask, if I connected 2 PCs with RJ-11 cables would the network connection be established in the same way as when I would connect 2 PCs with RJ-45 ethernet cables?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of options is to connect both to same network and transfer files with network sharing option or with hard disk reader get file's from disk:
https://www.ebay.com/itm/Hard-Disk-Drive-SATA-7-15-Pin-22-to-USB-2-0-Adapter-Cable-For-2-5-HDD-Laptop-CY/172688340405?epid=14007489979&hash=item283506f5b5:g:~pAAAOSwK6RZIpDv

or option with adapter to convert output RJ11 to RJ45 and than with normal RJ45 cable connect PC and Laptop. So point is that RJ11 has just 4 wires and is not for same purpose as RJ45 and i think even connection with RJ11 between two PC's will not work, but not sure because i don't never tested that.